# With Selenium WebDriver unable to switch to a popup

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

A pop will display asking to enter contact info. It is not an iframe, or alert or windows based popup. The URL does not even change. On the main homepage I click on 'Contact Us' and I get a pop up, looks like a form. How do I switch driver control to it and send input contact info??

Any help is alway highly appreciated.

Comment: if it's not an alert or an iframe, consider it to be a normal part of the page. You can find locator (xpath, css locator, ids) etc as for any other part of the page

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's what I thought too, but cannot find the locator. The site is "http://uptake.com". Issue is surfacing when the webdriver is clicking on "Contact Us" tab. I have tried a  few locators from the code of popup, but Webdriver never reaches them. Again, your help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share HTML for this popup here?? And let us know which element from the popup you want to locate?? And also share your tried attempt as well..

Comment: I see no issue on that page... maybe it's just synchronization? I submitted an example with synchronization as answer for your reference

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you have a specific problem, or it's just synchronization issue (which this example would address):

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); // used for synchronization

driver.get("http://uptake.com/");

// Make sure page was loaded
WebElement contactUs = wait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Contact Us")));

contactUs.click();

// Wait for Contact Us div to become visible 
// (by checking that title is displayed)
wait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
                By.xpath("//h2[contains(text(), 'Contact us below.')]")));

// Start filling form
driver.findElement(By.name("name")).sendKeys("John Smith");
// ... rest of the fields
driver.findElement(By.name("message")).sendKeys("Hello!");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Send']")).click();
```

Comment: Works like a charm!!! Thanks a bunch Kiril. It was the synchronization.